# Получить номер в рейтинге из таблицы

Tags: php, sql

Есть скрипт, который открывает всю таблицу пользователей, далее сортирует её по полю и выдаёт номер в рейтинге:

```
function num_tasks_rate($a) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `vk_id` FROM `users` WHERE `ban` != 2 ORDER BY `tasks_summ_done` DESC");
 for($i = 1; $i <= $data_rates = mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) {
  $data_rates = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  if($data_rates['vk_id'] == $a) {
   $n = $i;
   break;
  }
 }
 return $n;
}
```

Но такой код очень нагружает систему, видимо потому, что открывает 20.000 юзеров. Как можно оптимизировать или написать по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select count(u.vk_id)+1 
from users u
join (select tasks_summ_done from users where vk_id=$a) s
on u.tasks_summ_done>s.tasks_summ_done and u.ban <> 2
```

индексов для этого запроса нужно два:

- по полю `vk_id`
- по полю `tasks_summ_done`.

Answer (score 2):

Так, в лоб, вроде не решить. Самый простой способ - денормализовать базу данных и добавить поле "rating".
Альтернатива - это посчитать, сколько есть пользователей, которые имеют `tasks_summ_done` больше, чем у необходимого юзера. Что-то вроде такого (псевдокод):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `tasks_summ_done` FROM `users` WHERE `vk_id` = " . (int) $a);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `users` WHERE `ban` != 2 AND `tasks_summ_done` > " . (int) $tasks_summ_done_current);
```

Единственный нюанс - это неправильная обработка рейтинга пользователей с одинаковым `tasks_summ_done` - но это можно добавить дополнительным условием в последний запрос, что-то вроде этого:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `users` WHERE `ban` != 2 AND ( `tasks_summ_done` > " . (int) $tasks_summ_done_current . " OR (`tasks_summ_done` = " . (int) $tasks_summ_done_current . " AND `vk_id` >  " . (int) $a . ")) ");
```